# Asp.net mvc chart destroys page data

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I used asp.net mvc chart control to display chart in middle of my page. I have gone through some tutorials [here](https://www.asp.net/web-pages/overview/data/7-displaying-data-in-a-chart)

When I added my chart with the below code all page code is destroyed and only chart is displayed on page. I tried to pull chart from partial view and also tried to paste in between the code. But still I see only the chart and not the combination of my page output and chart. I also tried with

```
<img src="mypage.cshtml" />

@{
            var myChart = new Chart(width: 600, height: 400)
                .AddTitle("Chart Title")
                .AddSeries(
                    name: "Employee",
                    xValue: new[] { "Peter", "Andrew", "Julie", "Mary", "Dave" },
                    yValues: new[] { "2", "6", "4", "5", "3" })
                .Write();
}
```

Comment: as mentioned in the same tutorial I tried <img src="yourcshtml"> also. It didnt work.

Comment: If you insist of rendering a chart in your view check out this link https://github.com/martinobordin/Chart.Mvc this will work in your view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to keep your concerns separated and keep logic in the controller, which can be rendered by the View, rather than having logic in the View or a partial view.

In your controller I would have an action that returns a `FileResult`:

```
public FileResult Chart()
{
    var myChart = new Chart(width: 600, height: 400)
        .AddTitle("Chart Title")
        .AddSeries(
            name: "Employee",
            xValue: new[] { "Peter", "Andrew", "Julie", "Mary", "Dave" },
            yValues: new[] { "2", "6", "4", "5", "3" });

    return File(myChart.ToWebImage().GetBytes(), "image/jpeg");
}
```

Then in you view just call it using, for example:

```
<h1>Chart Example</h1>
<p>
    Your html markup etc.
</p>
<img src="@Url.Action("Chart")" />
```

Comment: in visual studio images generated will be hidden by default to the folder. Do I have to include them in project every time? Will the generated images overriden?

Comment: Not sure I follow sorry, the chart image will be created when the controller action is called.